# Using generic in the interface

Tags: c#, generics, boxing, unboxing

**Update:**

Heinzi is right. AutoCAD Polyline is reference type and not a struct. Good point. But I have simplified the scenario as what I am dealing with in the real application is an AutoCAD object which is struct. So please consider both as struct not reference type.

---

I am looking for the right approach to take in this situation and would appreciate if anyone can shed light or help me to better understanding.

There is an interface in the data access layer with two implementations to deal with two different providers: AutoCad and Sketchup APIs.

```
interface IEntity
{
    void object GetPoly();
    void void   InsertPoly(object poly);
}

class AutocadEntity
{
    void object GetPoly()
    {
         //calling Autocad APIs
         return Autocad Polyline object
    }
    void InsertPoly(object poly){...}
}
```

Autocad implementation of GetPoly would return Polyline object as this is what defined in Autocad APIs as polyline, whereas Sketchup would return Face object.

I have defined the return type(and the parameter) as object to deal with these different types. The cost is performance issue where boxing/unboxing happens. And it shows itself more boldly where the return/parameter is object[].

I first wondered making the method return/parameter type generic is the solution but then I think it wouldn't be as the implementations are type specific.

Comment: Why not have two different interfaces?  After all, even though it's a similar call, the function definition is different for the different implementations.

Comment: Is AutocadEntity the class that deal with Autocad and then there is SketchupEntity or does AutocadEntity deal with both?

Comment: @Jarrett Yes there is one SketchupEntity class as well implementing the same interface to deal with Skethcup APIs. Sorry for missing this part.

Comment: The generic interface is good solution but why do you think that the performance issue is related to boxing/unboxing? Are the `Polyline` or `Face` structs?

Comment: @Hamlet please see the update.

Comment: @ali How high up are you wanting to work with these two types?  Was your original intent to be able to work with a uniform interface?

Comment: @TyreeJackson Yes. That is the intention. To make this data access layer abstract so that other layers don't have to deal with specific APIs methods or types.

Comment: @TyreeJackson ..But then Heinzi is right. Even with a generic interface the problem is still there as there no longer be IEntity unique interface to pass around or refer to. It would either be IEntity<Polyline> or IEntity<Face>. So I still don't know what the answer is.

Comment: @ali Sounds like you need to use the adapter pattern.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to adapt the PolyLine and Face types to a single type that you would prefer to work with.  For example:

```
public abstract class BasePoly
{
    public abstract double X { get; set; }
    public abstract double Y { get; set; }
    public abstract double Width { get; set; }
    public abstract double Height { get; set; }
}
public abstract class BasePoly<T> : BasePoly
{
    public T poly { get; private set; }
    protected BasePoly(T poly) { this.poly = poly; }
}

public class PolyLineAdapter : BasePoly<PolyLine>
{
    public PolyLineAdapter(PolyLine poly) : base(poly) {}
    // override abstracts and forward to inner PolyLine instance at 'this.poly'

    public override double X { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } set { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    public override double Y { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } set { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    public override double Width { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } set { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    public override double Height { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } set { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

}

public class FaceAdapter : BasePoly<Face>
{
    public FaceAdapter(Face poly) : base(poly) {}
    // override abstracts and forward to inner Face instance at 'this.poly'

    public override double X { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } set { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    public override double Y { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } set { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    public override double Width { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } set { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    public override double Height { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } set { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }


}

interface IEntity
{
    BasePoly GetPoly();
    void   InsertPoly(BasePoly poly);
}

public abstract class Entity<TEntity> : IEntity
    where TEntity : BasePoly
{
    public BasePoly GetPoly()
    {
        return this.GetExternalPoly();
    }
    public abstract TEntity GetExternalPoly();
    public void InsertPoly(BasePoly poly)
    {
        this.InsertExternalPoly((TEntity) poly);
    }
    public abstract void InsertExternalPoly(TEntity poly);
}

public class AutocadEntity : Entity<PolyLineAdapter>
{
    public override PolyLineAdapter GetExternalPoly()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void InsertExternalPoly(PolyLineAdapter poly)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class SketchupEntity : Entity<FaceAdapter>
{
    public override FaceAdapter GetExternalPoly()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void InsertExternalPoly(FaceAdapter poly)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

// fills for third party classes
public class PolyLine {}
public class Face {}
```

Using the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), you provide a proxying layer to conform the two third party types to a type that you want to work with.

Keep in mind that this design assumes that you will only be working with one type of third party engine at a time.  If you will be working with **both** engines at the same time, then make the following change:

```
public class BasePoly
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
}

interface IEntity
{
    BasePoly GetPoly();
    void InsertPoly(BasePoly poly);
}

public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    public abstract BasePoly GetPoly();
    public abstract void InsertPoly(BasePoly poly);
}

public class AutocadEntity : Entity
{
    public override BasePoly GetPoly()
    {
        // retrieve external type, convert it to BasePoly and return that
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void InsertPoly(BasePoly poly)
    {
        // convert BasePoly to external type and insert that
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class SketchupEntity : Entity
{
    public override BasePoly GetPoly()
    {
        // retrieve external type, convert it to BasePoly and return that
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void InsertPoly(BasePoly poly)
    {
        // convert BasePoly to external type and insert that
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}

// fills for third party classes
public class PolyLine {}
public class Face {}
```

Also, if you are concerned about the cost of the adapter boxing or conversion operations (which I wouldn't be until you've actually measured and determined whether or not it needs to be optimized), then you can apply the adapter pattern to the callers that are consuming `IEntity` instead of the *PolyLineAdapter/FaceAdapter* or *AutocadEntity/SketchupEntity* types themselves.  Essentially, build a plugin engine.  You may be able to use Generics to abstract the common idioms between the two implementations.

Here is a dotnetfiddle example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UsFPM7

Comment: Thanks for the answer. PolylineAdapter derives from BasePoly<T> not BasePoly. Am I right? If true, then I suppose the above would give compile error on Entity<PolyLineAdapter>.

Comment: @ali Whoops, I forgot one to add the subclass signature for `BasePoly<T>` from `BasePoly`.  `PolyLineAdapter` inherits from `BasePoly<T>` which inherits from `BasePoly`, so, it should work fine.  I wrote that code on this site, so I didn't take the time to compile it.  I was just trying to get the idea across, but missed that one crucial point.

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but if I have understood the logic correctly then the AutocadEntity should implement IEntity as well as IEntity<TEntity>. As I suppose it is the IEntity that would work as a proxy on other layers. Is that right?

Comment: @ali Sorry, it was late at night when I made that update and I missed another crucial point.  I've updated the answer and provided a second option.  There is a third adapter option, but it would require seeing sample code for whatever calls the `IEntity.GetPoly()` and `IEntity.SetPoly()` methods.

Comment: @ali Also note the lack of generics in the second option.  There may still be an opportunity to use generics there but it would be to *DRY* whatever code is duplicated between the `AutocadEntity` and the `SketchupEntity` classes.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The second option is exactly what I use in the application. The amount of converting/wrapping that is needed when it comes to say fetching/inserting thousands of polylines was what made me thinking of generic interface. IEntity<T> where T is third party specific type is a great solution(no wrapping/converting/boxing is needed) but only as far as you work on this layer or not passing IEntity<T> around as that requires you to add another Adapter layer which again involves converting the third parties to this middle type.

Comment: Would you please explain what opportunity to use generics is there, as you refer to, in the second solution and what you mean by "to dry whatever code is duplicated between.."? Thanks.

Comment: @ali DRY refers to "Do not Repeat Yourself"  You can read about that at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself .  The opportunity to apply generics to the second solution may emerge based off of the code that you write to implement the `AutocadEntity` and `SketchupEntity` classes.  If you see code there that could have been copied and pasted between the two, then that code may be refactorable to use generics.  There may also be other options, but those would depend on the consumers of these classes (in other words, your other layers).

Comment: @ali Can you post some sample code on how you are using the objects between the time you call `GetEntity` and the time you call `InsertEntity`?  Also is there just one layer that directly uses the `GetEntity` and `InsertEntity` methods?  The more information you can provide, the better the chance that I can help you come up with an abstract design.

Comment: Yes Tyree it is only one layer that directly uses Insert/GetEntity methods. Is there possibly any point about this? I have taken the second approach you have posted plus having generic interface where the possibility is. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87194/discussion-between-tyree-jackson-and-ali).

Answer (score 4):

> The cost is performance issue where boxing/unboxing happens.

I don't think so. [Polyline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polyline(v=vs.110).aspx) is a class, not a struct. Thus, there is no boxing involved.

If this is in fact a performance bottleneck of your application, your performance is lost somewhere else. As always: measure before your optimize, or you might end up optimizing the wrong things.

I think your solution is perfectly fine. You *could* use generics and derive `AutocadEntity` from `IEntity<Polyline>`, but what would be the point? Since Polyline/Face is used both as input and output parameter in your interface, you can make `IEntity` neither co- nor contravariant. Thus, the most common base type of `IEntity<Polyline>` and `IEntity<Face>` would be `object`, which means that you can no longer just pass a general `IEntity` if you don't know the concrete type.

Comment: I think the benefit is the type safety.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Well, yes... at the cost of code duplication, since you'd have to split all your `DoSomething(IEntity)` methods in two: `DoSomething(IEntity<Polyline>)`, `DoSomething(IEntity<Face>)`. Of course, you could do a `DoSomething<T>(IEntity<T>)`, but then you're back at doing type checks and the type safety benefit is gone.

Comment: @Heinzi "Thus, the most common base type of IEntity<Polyline> and IEntity<Face> would be object, which means that you can no longer just pass a general IEntity if you don't know the concrete type."
Could you give an example on this please? thanks.

Comment: @Heinzi I suppose what you mean is that I no longer would be able to use a general IEntity anywhere else, say in another layer(e.x business layer).

Comment: @ali: Exactly. Unless you make `IEntity<T>` implement a general `IEntity`, but then you're back to objects...

Comment: @Heinzi So do still think generic interface is a best approach as there no longer is a unique IEntity interface to pass around. And as this was the first intention as TyreeJackson has mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two different classes implementing the interface I would think your best bet would be to make the interface generic.

```
interface IEntity<T>
{
   T GetPoly();
   void InsertPoly(T poly);
}
class AutocadEntity : IEntity<Polyline>
{
    Polyline GetPoly(){...}
    void InsertPoly(Polyline poly) {...}
}
```